# Determining threshold

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose you have the solution to the following problem

> $$ (1) \ \text{minimize} f(x) \\ \text{subject to} \  Ax = b$$

How do you determine the maximum $\epsilon$ such that the solution to (2)

> $$ (2) \ \text{minimize} f(x) \\ \text{subject to} \  Ax = b+\epsilon$$

can be accurately written in terms of the solution of (1) using a Taylor series expansion?

Comment: I imagine that would depend on what exactly is meant by "accurately".

Comment: Some more background would help. What do you know about $f$, for example?